# Edit Value in Collection by Index in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

If I have a collection named CollectionLabels and the content is below

```
UI Value Label  |Backend ->Fields
Label1          |Backend1
Label2          |Backend2
Label3          |Backend3
```

How can I edit the "Label2" to "Label2_New" by index?

I really want to avoid using the Loop Stage since it's really slow. Is there a way like:

```
CollectionLabels.UI Value Label (2) = "Label2_New"
```

I would really appreciate a fast moving code here.

Comment: Hey, could you please rephrase the question? I don't get it.

Comment: This functionality isn't provided out of the box with Blue Prism - you'll likely have to modify the bundled `Utility - Collection Manipulation` VBO or create a custom object and action with a C#/VB code stage to achieve this functionality of re-naming by index.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the statement "*I really want to avoid using the Loop Stage since it's really slow*"? Is this in debug mode or when run from the Control Room? Can you share any numbers you have to support this? Anecdotally, my experience has been exactly the opposite. Additionally, is there any reason this *must* be done by column index? It seems you have an idea of what the labels will be called, why not just use the pre-bundled `Rename Field` action in `Utility - Collection Manipulation`?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. Looping through a collection with more than 5000 entries will really take about more than 2 minutes. If I have to change the value of the entry in the UI Value Label of the 2500th index, then that will still take some time. It might be better to just have a function or object where in you just feed the index number and which field you want to input the value right?

Comment: <p>Below is an answer to your question that was posted within the Blueprism Community.</p><p>The answer was provided by [Ami Barrett](https://community.blueprism.com/network/profile?UserKey=205e0fe9-cb34-4b00-a12a-e79afd27ca90) and can be found here [RE: Edit Value in Collection by Index in Blue Prism](https://community.blueprism.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=2994f77f-760e-436c-a8f4-f2c57c1d54a9)

Answer (score 1):

This C# stage assumes that the index you're updating is always of type Text. Should be fairly easy to make modifications to accommodate other data types.

Inputs:
Collection - Collection  | 
Row - Number   |
Column - Number   |
newVal - Text

Outputs:
Modified Collection - Collection

```
Collection.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(Row)][Convert.ToInt32(Column)]=newVal;
Modified_Collection=Collection;
```